# Is there a "unified command" over all the defense forces in Washington D.C.?

Tags: united-states, military, police, washington-dc

A Unified Combatant Command is a task organized command structure used to coordinate forces around one objective. Examples include CENTCOM (https://www.centcom.mil/), which coordinates the armed forces in the Middle East. My question is, is there anything like that to coordinate the forces responsible for D.C., including the Secret Service (https://www.secretservice.gov/), Capitol Police (https://www.uscp.gov/), Army/Air National Guard (https://dc.ng.mil/), etc.? (I'm really not sure how to shoehorn research into this, the whole reason I'm posting this is because I can't find much.)

Comment: This might be a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_combatant_command I think that there's a lot of overlapping jurisdictions at play here, whether it's DHS, USNorthCom, or unconnected agencies at play (e.g., the Capitol Police Board which is outside the executive branch).

Answer (score -2):

Well, the President is Commander-in-Chief of the Armed Forces and there is also the Joint Chief of Staff. Given that the USA government is wary of concentrating all forces under one command - after all this is why the government has a tripartite structure with the legislative, executive and judicial branches; then it's only natural that there is a similar structure also in the military.

Comment: It might be only natural, but do you have some evidence to back this up? Note also that the Secret Service and the Capitol Police are not part of the military.

Comment: Do you take the   phrase "in Washington" to refer to where the command is, or where the forces are deployed?  I don't think the OP is asking about the command forces in Okinawa or Germany or...  Just DC

Comment: @stecen Meinikoff: You're being pedantic in describing the secret service as not part of the security forces which covers the armed forces in all its forms. It's also well attestrd that the framers of constitution were very concerned when they wrote the constitution should not be concentrated in a single pair of hands. It's also attested to in the general character of corporations when tte chairman, the ceo and the board of directors are not same and one guy. Thos is what I mean as being natural. Do you see it now?

Comment: @DJohnM: No comment.